# AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials in my Azure AD App

Tags: access-token, azure-active-directory

In my Azure AD App i am trying to retrieve Access Token in below section

```
 AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;
                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ClientId, appKey);
                            string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                            code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceID);

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
```

and i am getting below error

> {"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50011: The reply
>   address 'https://localhost:44301/' does not match the reply address
>   'https://localhost:44301' provided when requesting Authorization
>   code.\r\nTrace ID: fd34bd6b-37d5-4b66-85d0-657b27103049\r\nCorrelation
>   ID: ea970ddb-cab8-4949-b749-1b4a8d7b5a6b\r\nTimestamp: 2016-08-25
>   06:44:59Z"}

In Azure portal i have double checked that reply URL should match
[image]
what should be issue here?

Answer (score 5):

Your redirect URIs need to be **identical**. In your case, one has a slash at the end and the other doesn't.